# Changing fontFamily on ChartJS bar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've partially implemented [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org) in a project, but I can't figure out how to change the font that's displayed on the X and Y axes of a bar chart.

I've read the [ChartJS documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/), searched for examples on GitHub, etc. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I rest assured knowing the solution will involve a line of code and will be a startlingly stupid oversight on my part.

This code draws the chart I want, but with the default font:

```
var barChartLanguage = Chart.Bar(myCanvas, {
    data: dataLanguages,
    options: options,
    defaults: defaults
});
```

I tried changing the font in the `defaults` without success:

```
var defaults = {
    global: {
        // example font
        defaultFontFamily: "'Raleway'"
    }
};
```

And I tried changing it on the axis with `options`:

```
var options = {
    animation: {
        duration: 2000
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            ticks: {
                suggestedMin: 0,    // minimum will be 0, unless there is a lower value.
                // OR //
                beginAtZero: true,   // minimum value will be 0.
                suggestedMax: 10
            },
            gridLines: {
                display: false
            },
            pointLabels: {
                fontFamily: "'Raleway'"
            }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display: false
            }
        }],
    },
};
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add ticks.fontFamily to xAxes so it will look like this:

```
xAxes: [{
  gridLines: {
    display: false
  },
  ticks: {
    fontFamily: "Verdana",
  }
}],
```

Documentation: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales

Example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4asLpwd5/

Comment: So you have to add the font to both the axes as well as the legend? Isn't there a way to only set the font once? https://jsfiddle.net/askhflajsf/2520kmhg/

Comment: @MarkBoulder Yes! You can set it globally like this: `Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Helvetica';`. For more info, visit the [official documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html).

Comment: Notice that this option has changed in the meantime to `Chart.defaults.font.family` in the meantime. The link to the doc send by @rojadesign is still valid though!

Answer (score 10):

From version 3.x, onwards the syntax was changed.

Chart.js migration guide: [3.x Migration Guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartData,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false,
            }
        },
        scales: {
            x: {
                grid: {
                    display: false
                },
                ticks: {
                    font: {
                        family: 'Raleway', // Your font family
                        size: 14,
                    },
                },
            },
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                ticks: {
                    font: {
                        family: 'Raleway', // Your font family
                        size: 14,
                    },
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function (value, index, values) {
                        return '$' + value;
                    },
                },
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine. This should be the new accepted answer.